# Laravel policy view resource not triggered

Tags: laravel

I have this route :

```
Route::Resource('/additional_role_countries', 'AdditionalRoleCountryController');
```

In the controller I have this authorization :

```
class AdditionalRoleCountryController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->authorizeResource(AdditionalRoleCountry::class, 'additional_role_countries');
    }
}
```

And finally I have this policy for the model :

```
class AdditionalRoleCountryPolicy extends AbstractAuthorization
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump('je suis dans le construct de la policy');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any additional role countries.
     *
     * @param  Member  $member
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(Member $member)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the additional role country.
     *
     * @param  Member  $member
     * @param  AdditionalRoleCountry  $additionalRoleCountry
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(Member $member, AdditionalRoleCountry $additionalRoleCountry)
    {
        var_dump('titi');
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create additional role countries.
     *
     * @param  Member  $member
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(Member $member)
    {
        return $this->isAuthorizedBranch($member);
    }
}
```

My problem is that all is running  fine for the `POST` (= create). It sends a 403 error if necessary.

BUT for a `GET` (= view), it is not working. It even never executes the `__construct` methods. And it returns directly a **403**.

Why might this be happening?

### Edit

I tried to change this :

```
$this->authorizeResource(AdditionalRoleCountry::class, 'additional_role_countries');
```

with this :

```
$this->authorizeResource(AdditionalRoleCountry::class);
```

And now it seems it is working for the post and the get. Does it mean that the second parameter is not mandatory ?

Comment: Try removing the `/` in `Route::resource('/additional_role_countries', 'AdditionalRoleCountryController');` ?  `resource` should take a name

Comment: Hi Cbaconnier and thanks for your reply. I tried your solution without success. But I found something strange, see my edit.

Comment: @Dom I suspect it happens because you are passing the incorrect route parameter name to `authorizeResource`. `Route::Resource('additional_role_countries')` generates `additional_role_country` and you are passing `additional_role_countries`, therefore laravel does not find the model and cannot run the policy and just returns false by default (403). If you change the second parameter to  `additional_role_country` it should work.

Comment: GREAT, thanks you Remul. I changed to : `$this->authorizeResource(AdditionalRoleCountry::class, 'additional_role_country');` and all is working fine now. Thanks a lot. But tell me, is Laravel smart enough to transform the 'y' in 'ies' for the plural ? Unbelievable !

Comment: why would you need the plural? your model is singular and the route parameter is singular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are passing the incorrect route parameter to `authorizeResource`.

`Route::resource('additional_role_countries')` generates the following route parameter

```
additional_role_country
```

but you are passing

```
additional_role_countries
```

The problem is that Laravel can not find the model corresponding to `additional_role_countries` but still runs a `can` check but returns false by default (403).

**Solution**

Removing the second parameter or changing it to `additional_role_country` should solve the problem.

```
$this->authorizeResource(AdditionalRoleCountry::class, 'additional_role_country');

$this->authorizeResource(AdditionalRoleCountry::class);
```

**Why it worked for your store request**

As you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L90) Laravel does **not** use the second parameter for the methods `index`, `create` and `store`, instead it uses the Classname from the first parameter, in your case `AdditionalRoleCountry`.